# Support Reverse Group Membership Maintenance for OpenLDAP 2.3

Tags: ldap, openldap

I have some doubts about a topic openldap.

I am working with groups in ldap and I have the need to ask users of a certain group.

I have read that when you ask you can only filter by the field name and the value of this. And there is a way that when you add a user to a group, plus add the field member in the object group, adds a field memberOf to the object person. This is named "Reverse Group Membership Maintenance".

I understand that I have to load a module in openldap of this way "moduleload memberof.la" but openldap can not find it.

I have seen on the internet there is a package to install that module to the version 2.4.

My question is: Does the openfire version 2.3 supports this functionality?

I use:

Centos Linux ia3 2.6.18-194.32.1.el5 #1 SMP Wed Jan 5 17:53:09 EST 2011 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux.

Installed Packages
Name       : openldap
Arch       : i386
Version    : 2.3.43
Release    : 12.el5_6.7
Size       : 593 k
Repo       : installed

Regards

Answer (score 0):

There is a certain directory that Openldap will use to load modules from.  Its a configuration option that you can find.  Normally you don't have to do that as most modules are compiled statically into Openldap.  All I did (using the cn=config method, not slapd.conf) was add an olcOverlayConfig sub entry under my database object and it worked.

```
dn: olcOverlay={1}memberof,olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcConfig
objectClass: olcMemberOf
objectClass: olcOverlayConfig
objectClass: top
olcOverlay: {1}memberof
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the above one worked with OpenLDAP 2.3. I will not be surprised to head that it didnt worked without manual compilation.

First cn=config method is default with OpenLDAP 2.4
memberof overlay is shipped with OpenLDAP 2.4, with OpenLDAP 2.3 it cant be added because module library is missing.

Refer http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/appendix-changes.html

Installing OpenLDAP2.4 package in centos 5 wont work. Diffrent build environment & glibc version.

You can probably try fedora for OpenLDAP 2.4 to upgrade to Centos 6